# Node post to Facebook with Image

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

I have an application I am making that I  want to MAKE AUTOMATIC POSTS to Facebook. This means that want an Image+text sent to facebook. The image will be an image from cloudinary (where I am hosting my App)

1)User makes post
2)Statistical Algorithm determines whether or not to post...
3) Post Sent to the Facebook Page...

How would I do this. Is there already a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `facebook-node-sdk`, this is module for work with facebook over nodejs.

```
npm install fb
```

Here is good documentation:
https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk